# how to use openid for login system in website that allow only authorized users to access site

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

I m creating website that use openid for login system(login with gmail/yahoo accounts). I want only authorized users(users whose info. I already stored in my DB) should access site. 
With openid anyone can login with their gmail/yahoo accounts but I don't know how do I check current user info against my DB and allow access to only authorized users. I m using lightopenid for openid implementation.

Please give me any secure suggetions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You should link your users' OpenID identifiers to their user accounts. Then when a user logs in, check if the identifier has been linked to an account. If so, allow the login. If not, reject the login or allow them to bind the identifier to an account.

The identifier should be an unique URL as returned by the OpenID provider (e.g. Gmail or MyOpenID).

Comment: This is the right thing to do. It's a common misconception that using OpenID means you have to let the whole world in -- you don't. You can whitelist specific user id's as suggested here or even whitelist a given identity provider by domain or pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used lightopenid only [hybridauth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/)

But when someone logs in via my openid from Google their email address is supplied.
I would then compare that email with the data already stored in your database and link them up.

The problem you might find is that an email address is not sent back on some providers only an username. For example some of my Twitter users only have an username and no email address but this might not be an issue for you if your only using Google and Yahoo

Answer (score 0):

Well As per your User-Case there is no such build in mechanism and what you are aiming is i believe not a part of OpenId nor OAuth protocol.

These protocol work on the basis of providing authentication on there side based on the user-id/password provided by the end user.That means you can ask user to verify themself with these providers and these providers will let you know if the user is authenticated one or not as per there system.

Now whom you will give access to your services are your design decision.As in your case you want to give access to the users whose Email-id is with your database which simply require some server side code from your side.

Once user is redirected back from the OpenID system all you need to extract the email-id from the response and do a check against your DB and do whatever you want to do based on this check.

However before you mover forward want to point out some aspects.

1. Some OpenId system do not provide user-email so make sure you take this fact in to account while designing your application.
2. In alternate case you can work around with OpenID identifier as suggested by `bouke`

Answer (score 0):

LightOpenID provides an example (have a look at the files you downloaded). If `$openid` is your `LightOpenID` instance, you identify users with the URL stored at `$openid->identity` after `$openid->validate()` returns `TRUE`. Check that string against the one you have in your database and store the results in (e.g.) a PHP session. Once the user is validated, you don't need to use the URL if you don't want to. You can use your local user's ID if you prefer so.

```
<?php
require 'openid.php';
try {
    # Change 'localhost' to your domain name.
    $openid = new LightOpenID('localhost');
    if(!$openid->mode) {
        if(isset($_POST['openid_identifier'])) {
            $openid->identity = $_POST['openid_identifier'];
            # The following two lines request email, full name, and a nickname
            # from the provider. Remove them if you don't need that data.
            $openid->required = array('contact/email');
            $openid->optional = array('namePerson', 'namePerson/friendly');
            header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
        }
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    OpenID: <input type="text" name="openid_identifier" /> <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
    } elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
        echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
    } else {
        echo 'User ' . ($openid->validate() ? $openid->identity . ' has ' : 'has not ') . 'logged in.';
    print_r($openid->getAttributes());
    }
} catch(ErrorException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```